# How to get an assembly version without locking the file?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load an assembly without using Assembly.Load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646049/how-to-load-an-assembly-without-using-assembly-load)

How to get an assembly version without locking the file?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646049/how-to-load-an-assembly-without-using-assembly-load

Comment: @simplecoder. not an "exact duplicate" at all. while the answer you point to would allow me to get the version it requires the loading of the entire assembly into memory. Not ideal if I only need the version number. I found a much more optimal solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out

```
var targetVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(filePath).Version;
```