# FileInfo lock files!

Tags: .net, locking, fileinfo

Imagine a winform app, who copy updated assemblies from a source folder A to a destination folder B.
I use simple DirectoryInfo.GetFiles methods to fill a listview, comparing version of assembly in folder A and B; if some assemblies are newer, I start my update method.
In this method, before copying, I try if all file in B folder are not in use:

```
var B = new DirectoryInfo("myBfolder");
foreach (var file in aFolder.GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
        //File not in use
        File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //File in use!
    }
}
```

Well, because of previous UpdateListView code, that use FileInfo to get info to show, all my files results in use!

FileInfo lock files! Is this possible?

Can someone suggest a way to bypass this problem?

Thank you,
Nando

Comment: Are you sure they are no locked due to be loaded into your application (i.e. in use)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no, it is `File.Open` who lock files.

try to put it into using:

```
using(var file = File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
   // process here
}
```

Comment: I don't open any of theese files; I iterate files in folders, getting some infos like Name, Size, and Version.

I use a method to get version if file is a .NET assembly:
  private Version GetVersion(string fullpath)
  {
   if (File.Exists(fullpath))
   {
    try
    {
     Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullpath);
     if (ass != null)
     {
      return ass.GetName().Version;
     }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
     //Not an assembly file
     return new Version(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
   }
   return new Version(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

Probably I found the guilty?

Comment: Mmm...
Assembly is not a Disposable object; File.Exists() seems not to be a file locker, too.
I'm confused: this simple work is becoming a big headache!

Comment: @Ferdinando Santacroce locker is `Assembly.LoadFrom`

Comment: Commenting my GetVersion() method make thing run... Yes, is Assembly.LoadFrom!
To get version of an assembly in non-locking mode what can I do?
Copying file in a tmp folder and get version from these tmp files?

Thank you!
Nando

Comment: @Ferdinando Santacroce don't forget to accept the answer :) yes, you can avoid locking file by reading it to byte[] first as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031431/system-reflection-assembly-loadfile-locks-file

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey! :-)
Bye, Nando