# ReflectionTypeLoadException and COM-Interop

Tags: c#, reflection, com-interop

I have a .Net4 assembly which exposes an abstract, base class. In that same assembly, I have some code which reflects over all the files in a folder to build up a list of classes inheriting that base class. Here's the salient routine

```
private JsonTextWriter GetAvailableServices(JsonTextWriter writer, string path)
{
    try
    {            
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(FileFilter)
                                        .Where(f => IsAssembly(f.FullName))
                                        .Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(path, f.Name)))
                                        .SelectMany(a => GetLoadableTypes(a))
                                        .Where(p => typeof(ServiceProxy).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract)
                                        .Select(a0 => new { Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(a0), ClassName = a0.ToString() })
                                        .Aggregate(writer, (s, v) =>
                                        {
                                            s.WriteStartObject();
                                            s.WritePropertyName(ClassnameLabel);
                                            s.WriteValue(v.ClassName);
                                            s.WritePropertyName(DescriptionLabel);
                                            s.WriteValue(((ServiceProxy)v.Instance).Description);
                                            s.WriteEndObject();
                                            return s;
                                        });                
    }
    catch { Exception ex; }
    finally
    {
        writer.WriteEndArray();                
    }

    return writer;
}

private IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(Assembly assembly)
{            
    try
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
    }
}
```

I have a unit test which runs this code, targeting a specific folder, and it all works fine returning a list of classes inheriting the base class as JSON.

The above code sits in an assembly which is to be invoked from a COM (VB6) component. If I now invoke this same code from COM, targetting the same folder which the unit test targets, I get the reflection error and the loader info reports that it can't load the assembly which contains the above code. This only occurs in the `GetLoadableTypes` routine on the `GetTypes()` call when I am reflecting over an assembly which contains classes which do inherit the base class.

It sounds almost like a re-entrancy issue which only arises when COM is involved. I guess I could put the abstract base class into another assembly but wondered if there was something else going on.

Any explanation or pointers obviously gratefully received

Error Message:

> ReflectionTypeLoadException "Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information."

and in the LoaderExceptions:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'IfxGenDocService, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.":"IfxGenDocService,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

EDIT1: I changed things around a bit to extract the base class into its own assembly and am still getting the same error. Perhaps relevant, is that I have atest assembly which contains 3 classes inheriting the base class. I get 3 LoaderExceptions (all the same as reported above. I assume 1 for each class.

Comment: Can you add the full error message?

Comment: Thx .. just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may also happen when the assembly is locked by a process. Both of Assembly.LoadFile and Assmebly.LoadFrom methods lock the assembly and if you call this method more than one in a process, it is possible to get this exception on second call.

To avoid lock, you need to change this line

```
    .Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(path, f.Name)))
```

with

```
    .Select(f => Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, f.Name))))
```

it will work if all dependent assemblies are located in directories where you are traversing, otherwise you can check 
[System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile Locks File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031431/system-reflection-assembly-loadfile-locks-file) and [Loading Assembly to Leave Assembly File Unlocked](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/836907/Loading-Assembly-to-Leave-Assembly-File-Unlocked)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with this line

```
.Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(path, f.Name)))
```

It actually should have been

```
.Select(f => Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, f.Name)))
```

Since LoadFrom loads dependencies as well. I assume that when running unit tests, the dependencies must have already been loaded.